# renames file on a folder based on webpage

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I dont know whether this is proper question or not but I am learning. I have a webpage which has some buttons on it
like  **japan,tokyo,india,UK, USA**

and a folder which has images on it

```
YK08HJX_SYPTE_20140403170541594.jpg
YK08HJX_SYPTE_20140403170542194.jpg
1YK0BHJX_SYPTE1-PC_20140403170000670.jpg
```

. when user click s on any button on webpage  it should change the sypte1-PC or SYPTE to that button text.

```
YK08HJX_japan_20140403170541594.jpg
YK08HJX_INDIA_20140403170542194.jpg
1YK0BHJX_UK_20140403170000670.jpg.
```

any help would be appreciated.

this was my code: but dont how to interact directly with webpage on button click or href. text.

Listing A: RenameFiles.vbs

```
Dim WshShell, FileManagement, BrowseDialogBox, SelectedFolder, OldString, NewString, FullPath, TheFolder, FileList
Dim File, ThisFile, TheString, AlreadyRenamed, TempName, FlagName, Success, FindFlag, NewName, Dummy
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FileManagement = WScript.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set BrowseDialogBox = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set SelectedFolder = BrowseDialogBox.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select the folder containing the files you want to rename.", &H0001)
If InStr(1, TypeName(SelectedFolder), "Folder") = 0 Then
    WScript.Quit
Else
    OldString = InputBox("Enter the characters in the filename that you want to replace","Rename Files")
    If OldString = "" Then WScript.Quit
    NewString = InputBox("Enter the characters that you want to replace them with","Rename Files")
    ‘If NewString = "" Then WScript.Quit
End If
FullPath = SelectedFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(SelectedFolder.Title).Path
Set TheFolder = FileManagement.GetFolder(FullPath)
Set FileList = TheFolder.Files
Success = 0
For Each File In FileList
    ThisFile = File.Name
    TheString = InStr(ThisFile, OldString)
    AlreadyRenamed = InStr(ThisFile, "%")
    If (TheString <> 0) And (AlreadyRenamed = 0) Then
        Success = 1
        TempName = Replace(ThisFile, OldString, NewString)
        FlagName = "%" + TempName
        File.Name = FlagName
    End If
Next
For Each File In FileList
    ThisFile = File.Name
    FindFlag = InStr(ThisFile, "%")
    If FindFlag <> 0 Then
        NewName = Replace(ThisFile, "%", "")
        File.Name = NewName
    End If
Next
If Success = 1 Then
    Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Rename Files operation complete!",5,"Rename Files",64)
Else
    Dummy = WshShell.Popup ("Rename Files operation failed! Please repeat the operation.",0,"Rename Files",16)
End If
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you were having trouble interacting with the webpage or button click. So I'll help you with that portion. You can create a single button-click event that is fired whenever any of your buttons are clicked. That way you can keep your code in a single sub. Here's an example:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="vbscript">
    Sub DoClick(strText)

        ' strText will hold the name of the button that was clicked.
        ' Use it to rename your files.

    End Sub
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="DoClick('Japan')" value="Japan" />
<input type="button" onclick="DoClick('USA')" value="USA" />

</body>
</html>
```